Issue with Adding Blocklists in uBlock Origin's Source Code via assets.json
I've recently cloned uBlock Origin's source code repository and attempted to add blocklists by editing the assets.json file.   However, despite making the necessary changes, building the project using make, and then installing the extension in the browser, the blocklists are still not being added.
Here's the unedited snippet of the relevant section from ubo's assets.json :
{
    "assets.json": {
        "content": "internal",
        "updateAfter": 13,
        "contentURL": [
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gorhill/uBlock/master/assets/assets.json",
            "assets/assets.json"
        ],
        "cdnURLs": [
            "https://ublockorigin.github.io/uAssetsCDN/ublock/assets.json",
            "https://ublockorigin.pages.dev/ublock/assets.json",
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gorhill/uBlock@master/assets/assets.json",
            "https://cdn.statically.io/gh/gorhill/uBlock/master/assets/assets.json"
        ]
    },
    "public_suffix_list.dat": {
        "content": "internal",
        "updateAfter": 19,
        "contentURL": [
            "https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat",
            "assets/thirdparties/publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat"
        ]
    },
    "ublock-badlists": {
        "content": "internal",
        "updateAfter": 29,
        "contentURL": [
            "https://ublockorigin.github.io/uAssets/filters/badlists.txt",
            "assets/ublock/badlists.txt"
        ],
        "cdnURLs": [
            "https://ublockorigin.github.io/uAssetsCDN/filters/badlists.txt",
            "https://ublockorigin.pages.dev/filters/badlists.txt",
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/uBlockOrigin/uAssetsCDN@main/filters/badlists.txt",
            "https://cdn.statically.io/gh/uBlockOrigin/uAssetsCDN/main/filters/badlists.txt"
        ]
    }
}

I expected a modification to include the specified blocklist in the built uBlock Origin extension, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended. Need to add blocklists.txt from my github repository as a default blocklists in ubo extenstion.
Can anyone provide guidance on why the blocklists aren't being added even after editing the assets.json file? Am I missing any additional steps or configurations that are necessary for integrating custom blocklists into the uBlock Origin build process?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
